# question about gradation of a ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

I was reading Mumford's 'Red book on varieties and schemes', when I came across the following paragraph:

[image]

I am confused about meaning of the phrase "We let $k(X)$ be the zeroth graded piece of the localization of $R$ ..." and want to be sure I have understood it correctly.

Please correct me if I'm wrong: If $S$ denotes the set of all homogeneous elements of $R$, then $S$ is multiplicatively closed subset of $R$, and we give a gradation on $S^{-1}R$ by defining $\deg(f/g) := \deg(f)-\deg(g)$ for homogeneous elements $f,g\in R$. This defines a gradation on $S^{-1}R$, and $k(X)$ is the degree zero part of it.

But then what is the degree of the element $0$ in $S^{-1}R$? because I am getting trouble proving that $S^{-1}R$ is the direct sum of its graded pieces. I can see that they span the ring, but why is the sum *direct*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In any graded ring one doesn't assign any degree to $0$ (for this is in any graded piece). Btw, your argument about $k(X)$ is ok.

Comment: I know this question is old, but I am struggling with a similar problem and was hoping we could bring it back. Are we to understand each $R_n$ as $M_n/P_n$, where $M_n:=${homogeneous polynomials in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ of degree n} and $P_n:=${homogeneous polynomials in $P$ of degree n}? In which case, how does one consider $K(X)$, as Mumford defines it, as a ring?